# Show values from helper method in drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a hash constant in my ROR application. I want to show the `names` from the hash constant to drop down.

helper.rb

```
PRODUCE_GROWING_METHODS  = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Conventional'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Organic'},
  ]

def produce_growing_methods
    PRODUCE_GROWING_METHODS  
  end
```

_produce.haml

```
= f.simple_fields_for :produce_details do |pd|
  = pd.input :produce_growing_method, :collection => produce_growing_methods.collect { |x| [x[0], x[1]] }, :prompt => "Select Growing Method"
```

I tried as shown above in `_produce.haml` but i am getting the empty drop down. `Names` from the constant are not populated in drop down.

Can any one help me how to show the `names` from the  `PRODUCE_GROWING_METHODS` hash constant to a drop down.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the `CONSTANT` is available to the helper? Where is the constant declared?

Comment: try `produce_growing_methods.map {|x| [x[:id],x[:name]]}` because [0] and [1] will return nil. In a Hash the `[]` method is looking for an element by key and since you have no key `0` or `1` you will always get nil for this. the other option would be to make  `PRODUCE_GROWING_METHODS` a multi-dimensional array like `[[1,'Conventional'],[2,'Organic']]` then you could pass it directly in as the collection like `collection: produce_growing_methods`

Comment: @engineersmnky You are correct. Please post this as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should map the hash by keys. In your case the keys are `:id` and `:name`:

```
produce_growing_methods.map { |x| [x[:id], x[:name]] }
```

In reality you are always better of using a generic solution rather then manual mapping.
Here is a better way of achieving the same, but it will work as well for array of thousand hashes:

```
ary = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Conventional'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Organic'},
]
ary.map(&:values)
#=> [[1, "Conventional"], [2, "Organic"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation!